# C# find row index (row number) in datagridview upon button click

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, row

This is the basic ui of my app and when i click the red (engaged room) button it should highlight the row in datagridview with cusid = 1, and no other row should be clickable.

[image: this is the datagridview and the red button]

[image: this picture might explain better what i want to say]

I'm not able to find the row index (row number) in the dgv where cusid = 1, so that i can select/highlight it, specifically.

Could this be done, any helps?

I have a bookmyroom app and the i add my datagridview by using following code:

```
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
string query = "select id,cusid,cusname,timein,
timeout,duration,amount,remark from entry";
command.CommandText = query;
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

and my checkbox column using this code;

```
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
checkColumn.Name = "logout";
checkColumn.HeaderText = "Logout";
checkColumn.Width = 50;
checkColumn.ReadOnly = false;
checkColumn.FillWeight = 10;
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(checkColumn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you read the answer you should know in a windows application you can have multiple forms and you can do some tasks in other forms. For example, you can make your grid read only, then select a row and click on a check out button and perform editing actions in another form.

But based on your question:

You can assign an event handler for all buttons and then in the handler, for each row you can look in `cusid` column (column with index = 1) and check if the value equals to the button `Text` then activate `logout` cell, else make the row readonly:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        //This is the last row, ignore it.
        if (item.IsNewRow)
            continue;

        //Compare value of cell1 with button text
        //I supposed button.Tex is the value that you want to compare with cusid 
        if (item.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == button.Text)
        {
            //Make row editable
            item.ReadOnly = false;

            //Select the logout cell
            this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = item.Cells[5];
        }
        else
        {
            //Make row readonly
            item.ReadOnly = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you're a legend, thanks, you always get it, cant imagine this place without you.

Comment: You are welcome and thank you so much for your kind response :)

Comment: By the way when you accept an answer, you can kindly vote for it by click on up arrow near the answer. While you can accept only one question, but you can vote for as many answers as you find helpful, including the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

literally off the top of my head and untested, you may want to try something like this to get the next row down (if that's really what you need):

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

        if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn &&
            e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            var nextRowNum = senderGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex] + 1;
            // do what you need with the custId cell/value
            // i.e. select that row and hilite it etc
        }
    }
```

apologies if I've misunderstood your requirement for the images you added.